# Passing parameters for my jquery_mobile application

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({url: 'myurl', {data:{parameters : params}},
         success: function(result){
            $("#container").html(result);
         }

        });
```

I have passed the parameters in the way above, but when i raise the elament its returning me the nill value.
How can i pass the parameter here, as im building a jquery_mobile application, any suggestions!!

Comment: Could this be something to do with the server code you have on the other end of this project?  What does the full query string look like?  Can you console log result?

Comment: @AgnosticDev in the above code its same as my original code, here when i click on the submit button, the contents of the url page should be displayed.

Comment: OK, so what are the parameter you are passing to the URL doing?  Are they performing correctly?

Comment: var pars = "emp_no="+$("#Usertable_employee_no").val();
this is the parameter im passing(employee_number), its not performing correctly, whether my way of passing parameter is correct or should i give the other way plz suggest me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using your parameters as an object.
Like this:

```
   parametes = {
     'emp_no': $("#Usertable_employee_no").val(),
     'key' : 'value'
   };
```

I would also ry using Ajax like this:

```
   $.ajax{(
      url: 'url',
      data: parameters,
      success: function(result){
          //perform logic on result
      }
   });
```

Comment: thanks but even with your code, when i raised the object its showing nill value...

Comment: thanks a lot bro now its working fine, and i have one more problem

Comment: i have a issue like when i load the locations, the floors under that particular location should be loaded.. Now its loading fine but after loading the style of the page is changed which is not required

Comment: excellent, if it worked out for you, don't forget to check it as the correct answer.

Comment: The style of the page could be altered if you are loading in more HTML that could possibly be throwing off how you stylesheet renders elements on your page.  This is just a guess.  To say for sure I would say to post a new question with all new code.

Comment: when i save the data it is saving multiple times, can u plz help me out.

Comment: Hello, yeah I am sure we can figure something out.  Can you post a new question relating to the specific issue at hand and supply all the code that is involved with you issue.  Then add a link relating to that issue here.

Comment: plz checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154744/styling-issue-with-the-ajax?noredirect=1#comment28333667_19154744